# CEFSharp3 ChromiumWebBrowser fails in rendering KML

Tags: chromium, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I am trying to render a page having KML using Chromium browser but it fails with the following error:

"The operation failed because it would cause the application to exceed its storage quota."

The same page is rendered correctly using Google chrome.

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: - Which version of CefSharp are you using?
 - please provide a sample page for others to reproduce the problem - not being familiar with KML and the page/web app you use "a page with KML" makes it pretty hard for others to help you

Comment: The version is CefSharp.Wpf 37.0.0. The page is an internal page created from server. KML is sent as text from server and is saved in local storage then rendered on the page. everything works fine using Google chrome but it doesn't work using CefSharp.WPFExample.Minimal.

Comment: Ironically it also works on Cefsharp.WPFExample.Minimal when running on debug mode with devtools while adding break points on certain part of the code

Comment: Ah! The explanation with local storage made me read the issue in a completely new way! I don't think it's an issue with the CefSharp codebase the - possibly an issue worth debugging with the upstream CEF project codebase. Try isolating the issue with the CEF test app from http://cefbuilds.com ... also try tweaking  local storage and cache quota related CLI parameters like http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#unlimited-storage. They can be used both with CEF and CefSharp

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tested the latest Chromium from the  cefbuilds.com using Trunk and it is working with no problem. I reckon something wrong with Cefsharpwpf 3.37.

Comment: CefSharp 37 is based on CEF branch 2062 from http://cefbuilds.com so you can narrow it down using that version. There is also a CefSharp 39.0.0-pre01 NuGet built from the CefSharp 2171 branch on GitHub you can try comparing. The exact CEF rev it is based on is 3.2171.1949.

Comment: I tested CefSharp 39.0.0-pre and it still fails in rendering the page. I downloaded the source cef_binary_3.2171.1949_windows64 which is used in Cefsharp 39 and ironically i found that if i set the startpage to CefSimple project and compile and run the result executable "cefSimple.exe" fails to render the kmls on the page but if set the startpage to cefClient project and compile run then the cefClient.exe succeed in rendering the page with kmls. I am now trying to see the difference between those two c++ projects

Comment: Great! At least now it's isolated/reproducible with `cefsimple.exe` alone. I'd suggest you post about the issue in the discussion forum of the CEF project. What VS version are you using? It could be a compiler version issue?

Comment: Oh yeah, and please update your original question above with your new findings from our discussion above so it's up-to-date!

Comment: I am using Visual studio 2013. Ok i will post the issue in Cef discussion forum.

Comment: Someone from Cef forum kindly responded as follows. "You need to implement CefRequestHandler::OnQuotaRequest to approve the requested storage size". I inspected the Cefclient and i realized that this method has been implemented but it is missing in CefSimple. I think we know now what exactly is the problem but how how can i implement it in CefSharp.WPF?

Comment: I agree! I wasn't aware of `CefRequestHandler::OnQuotaRequest` in the CEF API. It will require a (little) bit of C++ and C# skills. I hope you are up for that challenge with a bit of support! I suggest you move the discussion to a new issue in the CefSharp GitHub repo as this has turned into a need for a CefSharp enhancement. To get an idea of what it takes to expose a handler method in CefSharp see e.g. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/pull/396/files ...

Comment: Thanks for all your help and support. I eventually managed to fix this issue by modifying the method  "OnQuotaRequest" in file request_handler_cpptoc.cc in project libcef_dll_wrapper. i compiled that both in 32 and 64 bit then used it in Cefsharp.Core project of the Cefsharp3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is among the discussions and comments under [jornh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/210723/jornh) direction as follows:

I managed to fix this issue by modifying the method "OnQuotaRequest" in file request_handler_cpptoc.cc in project libcef_dll_wrapper. i compiled that both in 32 and 64 bit then used it in Cefsharp.Core project of the Cefsharp3.